# In yacc, if given input do not match any rule, how can we get back the input in the same format in the output

Tags: error-handling, default, yacc

Please find the my code below:

```
function_definition
    : declaration_specifiers  declarator declaration_list {printf("in function definition \n");}compound_statement
    | declaration_specifiers  declarator {printf("in function definition \n");}compound_statement
    | declarator declaration_list {printf("in function definition \n");} compound_statement
    | declarator {printf("in function definition \n");} compound_statement {my_fun($<block_item_struct>2); printf("in function definition\n");}
    | direct_declarator ';'  {
                            $<fun_ptyp>$ = $<multi_type>1;
    }

    | error  {char * text ; $<symbol_table>$->cb = malloc(sizeof(struct code_block));text = strdup(yytext);$<symbol_table>$->cb->function_call= text;$<symbol_table>$->cb->pos =yylineno;
                *yytext=NULL;printf("error: %s at line no %d\n",$<symbol_table>$->cb->function_call,$<symbol_table>$->cb->pos);**
             }
    ;
```

Note: In case any input is not matching the rules, error token is matched and its returning me the input tokens but what I require is in the same format in which the input was , without tokenizing the input. In one `char*` if it could return the non matching input.

For example:

Input is comment lines which I want to simply copy back to my output file:

```
Ex: /* This function takes care of tree implementation .
    The parameters passed are char* and  int */
```

Comment: The short answer is that you can't. The input has already been tokenized. NB `yacc` does not use regular expressions.

Comment: Is there a way we can bypass tokenizing by lex and have a default rule in yacc to match all that don't match any other rule.